# JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jp) not working in Jar file

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

When i print report commenting `JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(JasperPrint)`     report gets shown fine in **Jar file**. Otherwise report gets stuck in this function and report viewer doesnt come , even not giving any error. In Netbeans it is working fine. i am working in JDK8u25(32bits). Here is my code for Report Printing:

```
public void PrepareReport(ResultSet rs) {
       try{
             String reportName ="/com/mmts/reports/challan.jasper";
             InputStream st = getClass().getResourceAsStream(reportName);
             JasperReport jr= (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(st); 
             JasperPrint jp = 
            JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr,new HashMap<>(),new JRResultSetDataSource(rs));
            JRViewer jv = new JRViewer(jp);  
            JFrame jf = new JFrame();
            jf.getContentPane().add(jv);
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jp);
            jf.validate();
            jf.setVisible(true);
            jf.setTitle("Challan");
            jf.setSize(new Dimension(1200,600));
            jf.setLocation(20,20);
            jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
            }catch(JRException ex){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
                    }
            }
```

Here is my console output for Packaging:

```
ant -f D:\\Metro\\MMTS\\NetBeansProjects\\MMTS -Djar.archive.disabled=true -Dnative.bundling.type=image build-native
Detected JavaFX Ant API version 1.3
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: D:\Metro\MMTS\NetBeansProjects\MMTS\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory D:\Metro\MMTS\NetBeansProjects\MMTS\build
clean:
deps-jar:
Created dir: D:\Metro\MMTS\NetBeansProjects\MMTS\build
Updating property file: D:\Metro\MMTS\NetBeansProjects\MMTS\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: D:\Metro\MMTS\NetBeansProjects\MMTS\build\classes
Created dir: D:\Metro\MMTS\NetBeansProjects\MMTS\build\empty
Created dir: D:\Metro\MMTS\NetBeansProjects\MMTS\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 24 source files to D:\Metro\MMTS\NetBeansProjects\MMTS\build\classes
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Copying 5 files to D:\Metro\MMTS\NetBeansProjects\MMTS\build\classes
Copied 2 empty directories to 1 empty directory under D:\Metro\MMTS\NetBeansProjects\MMTS\build\classes
compile:
Created dir: D:\Metro\MMTS\NetBeansProjects\MMTS\dist
Copying 33 files to D:\Metro\MMTS\NetBeansProjects\MMTS\dist\lib
Launching <fx:jar> task from C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar
Launching <fx:deploy> task from C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar
Note: To create native bundles the <fx:deploy> task may require external tools. See JavaFX 2.2+ documentation for details.

Launching <fx:deploy> in native packager mode...
No base JDK. Package will use system JRE.
Creating app bundle: MMTS in D:\Metro\MMTS\NetBeansProjects\MMTS\dist\bundles
Result application bundle: D:\Metro\MMTS\NetBeansProjects\MMTS\dist\bundles
Deleting: D:\Metro\MMTS\NetBeansProjects\MMTS\dist\MMTS.html
Deleting: D:\Metro\MMTS\NetBeansProjects\MMTS\dist\MMTS.jnlp
Deleting: D:\Metro\MMTS\NetBeansProjects\MMTS\dist\MMTS_browser.jnlp
build-native:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 17 seconds)
```

Saving the generated report in pdf formatt is a must for me. Please Help.

Comment: Have i asked an improper question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok...now i got the solution.
Problem was in the version of itextpdf and lowagie jars.
Earlier i was having the jars included as follows:

```
(1)itextpdf-2.1.7.jar
(2)com.springsource.com.lowagie.text-2.0.8.jar
```

Now i have changed them to the following :

```
(1)itextpdf-5.5.3.jar
(2)com.lowagie.text-2.1.7
```

and due to this i can view my report in report viewer print to printer or can save in pdf

Now final code is as follows:

```
public void PrepareReport(ResultSet rs){
        try{
             String reportName ="/com/mmts/reports/challan.jasper";
             InputStream st = getClass().getResourceAsStream(reportName);
             JasperReport jr= (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(st); 
             Map parameters = new HashMap();
             JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr,parameters,new JRResultSetDataSource(rs));

                JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jp);     
                JasperViewer jv=new JasperViewer(jp,false);
                jv.setTitle("Challan");
                jv.setVisible(true);

                }catch(JRException ex)
                {
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
                }
    }
```

thanks